# Classification - What can we use when the number of dimensions is greater than the number of samples?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, data-mining, prediction

I've read on the scikit-learn website that SVM is a good choice when the number of dimensions is greater than the number of samples.

I would like to know what you think (as experienced users) is the more efficient in these cases where the class to predict is binary.

And especially what to do when the number of labeled samples is about 50.

Algorithms that should work ? Things to care about ?

Comment: When number of samples is that small, I doubt you can learn anything from it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think, what can be done when the number of sample is that small ? Maybe something that will be more accurate each time a new sample is known ?

Comment: What is the dimensionality? If you are fine with linear models, sparse linear models such l1 penalized SVM might be good.

Comment: @AndreasMueller For each line (~50) I have thousands of numerical values. The target is binary (0 or 1). I think I have to do some dimensionality reduction because I have two much features. I'm wondering also about flag columns, will they help if I add them.

Comment: My mistake, I don't have thousands of features, only 100.
I think it's better to predict.

Comment: You could even with thousands. Just use a regularized model.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dense data, and n < d, you have a high risk of overfitting: each dimension or differences of dimensions could uniquely identify your training records.

That doesn't mean it won't work, only that you have to be extra careful when evaluating your method, because of the high risk of overfitting.

Methods that only use one dimension at a time - such as decision trees - could be less affected. In particular, if you apply pruning techniques to your tree.

Comment: It's numerical data like 1.4102. What to do if each feature has unique values ?